# MiniMagick::Error (You must have ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick installed) on Redmine 4.2.3 and FreeBSD 13.0

Tags: imagemagick, freebsd, redmine, minimagick

I get an error about a missing **ImageMagick** installation when exporting a **Redmine Gantt** chart to **PNG**. But I cannot pin down the reason because everything seems to be installed correctly, and I have an identical server with the same OS, same Redmine version / config and the same packages etc. installed. On the other (test) server, it all seems to work.

What could be the issue or how can I pin it down?

**Some more in depth information:**

**Error in the logs:**

```
Started GET "/projects/migratie/issues/gantt.png

MiniMagick::Error (You must have ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick installed):

lib/redmine/helpers/gantt.rb:399:in `to_image'
app/controllers/gantts_controller.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in show'
app/controllers/gantts_controller.rb:42:in `show'
lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:61:in `sudo_mode'
```

**Redmine information:**

```
Redmine 4.2.3.stable
Standaard beheerderaccount gewijzigd    
Bestandsrepository schrijfbaar  
Plugin assets map schrijfbaar (./public/plugin_assets)  
MiniMagick beschikbaar (optioneel)  
ImageMagick comversie beschikbaar (optioneel)   
ImageMagick PDF support available (optional)    

Environment:
  Redmine version                4.2.3.stable
  Ruby version                   2.7.4-p191 (2021-07-07) [amd64-freebsd13]
  Rails version                  5.2.6
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
  Mailer queue                   ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::AsyncAdapter
  Mailer delivery                sendmail
SCM:
  Git                            2.33.1
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  easy_gantt                     1.13
  redmine_agile                  1.6.2
  redmine_checklists             3.1.20
  redmine_contacts               4.3.4
  redmine_contacts_helpdesk      4.1.12
  redmine_contacts_invoices      4.2.5
  redmine_crm_mailchimp          1.0.4
  redmine_datetime_custom_field  1.0.4
  redmine_drive                  1.1.1
  redmine_editauthor             0.11.0
  redmine_favorite_projects      2.1.1
  redmine_finance                2.1.7
  redmine_helpdesk_contact_sync  0.0.4.1
  redmine_issue_templates        1.1.0
  redmine_people                 1.6.1
  redmine_products               2.1.4
  redmine_questions              1.0.2
  redmine_reporter               2.0.0
  redmine_resources              1.0.6
  redmine_tint_issues            1.2.1
  redmine_view_issue_description 0.0.2
  redmine_zenedit                2.0.1
  redmineup_tags                 2.0.11
  stopwatch                      0.2.0
```

**Verified steps:** please bear in mind that it works on the test server.

1. Same FreeBSD version 13.0-release
2. Same Redmine 4.2.3 version, configuration and plugins (I did a directory compare)
3. ImageMagick7 installed, tested (convert and magick command) and executes as www user, available in the path env. Same options and confirmed PNG support.
4. Gem mini_magick (4.11.0, 4.10.1) installed.
5. Bundle: Using mini_magick 4.11.0 in /usr/local/www/redmine
6. configuration.yml (with two leading spaces): imagemagick_convert_command: /usr/local/bin/convert
7. Other converts (eg. pdf) in Redmine seem to work fine on both servers.
8. Moving to another database does not change a thing.
9. Apache config is identical.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing `MiniMagick.cli = :imagemagick` to `lib/redmine/helpers/gantt.rb`

```rb
if Redmine::Configuration['imagemagick_convert_command'].present?
    MiniMagick.cli_path = File.dirname(Redmine::Configuration['imagemagick_convert_command'])
    MiniMagick.cli = :imagemagick
end
```